# Trying to get program to repeat

Tags: java, loops, do-while

The program checks to see if the email address entered contains a @ and a .edu
if it doesn't it needs to go back through the steps, I think I can use a do-while,but I haven't got one to work yet, how would I nest my if-else statements in a do-while? Thanks!

```
if (UserEmail.contains("@")) {
    if (UserEmail.contains(".edu")){
        System.out.print("Please create a password: ");
        PassWord = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println(UserEmail.replaceAll("@\\S+?\\.edu\\b", ""));
        System.out.print("Your password is " + PassWord);
    } else {
        System.out.print("email is not valid Please, try again.")
    } else {
        System.out.print("email is not valid Please, try again.");
        // at this point it should repeat and ask for the email again
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code with do-while construct and let us see what went  wrong.

Comment: even your if-s return true, it does not guarantee that email address is correct. For instance: `a@b@.,.:\*sc@.edu@` will pass your verification.

Comment: I love this site, thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to simplify your `if-else` code consider using

```
if (UserEmail.contains("@") && UserEmail.contains(".edu")) {
 .
 .
}
```

this can be wrappped in a `do - while`

```
do {
  if (UserEmail.contains("@") && UserEmail.contains(".edu")) {
  .
  .
  break;
  }
  System.out.print("email is not valid Please, try again.")
} 
while (true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define method `isValid(String email, String password,... some more params)` aand put all your check logic in the method.

Write something like this

```
while (!isValid(the params)) {
   //ask all the credentials
}
```

Comment: i prefer this option also, i intended to write it but you are the first one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add something like `boolean correctEmail = false` before your logic and at the beginning of your `if` statements, you write `while(!correctEmail) {`

At the end of your password-creation you set `correctEmail` to `true` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty straight forward.

```
bool trigger = (true/false);
do {
    if (...) {
        if (...){...}
        else if (...) {...}
        else {
            print out retry statement;
            trigger = false; 
        }
    }
}
while (trigger == true);
```

Don't forget a semicolon at the end.